WooCommerce- Apply Conditional Discount after Shipping
I have created a some custom shipping and discount rules for my custom user- 'dealer'. The problem is I want to apply my conditional discount before Shipping fee is applied. For some reason it displays after.
I am unsure why this occurs. How can I update my function to display the discount before my shipping fee is added.
I have added my whole rule for context.
    // Here we Apply our discounnnts for dealers before shipping fees are calculated
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'apply_dealer_discounts', 10, 1);

// APly custom shipping rules for dealers after discounts
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_shipping_rules_dealer', 20, 2);

function apply_dealer_discounts($cart) {
    // Get the current user
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    // Check if the user role is 'dealer'
    if (in_array('dealer', (array) $current_user->roles)) {
        $cart_total = $cart->cart_contents_total;
        $core_or_seasonal = false;
        $keg_count = 0;

        // Iterate through the cart items
        foreach ($cart->get_cart() as $cart_item) {
            $product = wc_get_product($cart_item['product_id']);

            // Check for Core or Seasonal categories
            if (has_term(['core', 'seasonal'], 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'])) {
                $core_or_seasonal = true;
            }

            // Check for Keg category
            if (has_term('keg', 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'])) {
                $keg_count += $cart_item['quantity'];
            }
        }

        // Apply my discounts- This should apply before shipping.
        if ($core_or_seasonal) {
            $discount = $cart_total * 0.10;
            $cart->add_fee(__('Core or Seasonal Discount', 'woocommerce'), -$discount);
        }

        if ($keg_count > 0) {
            $discount = $cart_total * 0.05;
            $cart->add_fee(__('Keg Discount', 'woocommerce'), -$discount);
        }
    }
}

function custom_shipping_rules_dealer($rates, $package) {
    // Get the current user
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    // Check if the user role is 'dealer'
    if (in_array('dealer', (array) $current_user->roles)) {
        // Initialize variables
        $total_items = 0;
        $core_or_seasonal = false;
        $keg_count = 0;

        // Iterate through the cart items
        foreach ($package['contents'] as $item) {
            $product = wc_get_product($item['product_id']);
            $categories = $product->get_category_ids();

            // Check for Core or Seasonal categories
            if (has_term(['core', 'seasonal'], 'product_cat', $item['product_id'])) {
                $core_or_seasonal = true;
                $total_items += $item['quantity'];
            }

            // Check for Keg category
            if (has_term('keg', 'product_cat', $item['product_id'])) {
                $keg_count += $item['quantity'];
            }
        }

        // Get the shipping zone
        $zone_id = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zone_matching_package($package);
        $zone = new WC_Shipping_Zone($zone_id);
        $zone_name = $zone->get_zone_name();

        // Debug statements
        error_log('Zone Name: ' . $zone_name);
        error_log('Keg Count: ' . $keg_count);
        error_log('Core or Seasonal: ' . ($core_or_seasonal ? 'Yes' : 'No'));
        error_log('Total Items: ' . $total_items);

        // Calculate shipping cost based on conditions
        foreach ($rates as $rate_key => $rate) {
            // Apply rules for Core or Seasonal categories
            if ($core_or_seasonal) {
                if ($total_items >= 10) {
                    $rates[$rate_key]->cost = 0;
                } else {
                    $rates[$rate_key]->cost = 60 * $total_items;
                }
            }

            // Apply rules for Keg category
            if ($keg_count > 0) {
                if ($zone_name === 'Bangkok Metropolitan Region') {
                    $rates[$rate_key]->cost = 0;
                } else {
                    $rates[$rate_key]->cost = 300 * $keg_count;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $rates;
}


Shipping costs doesn't take into account fees or negatives fees (discounts).

@LoicTheAztec You are correct. For some reason I made some miscalculations.
